# In React Native Android How to check internet connection is online /offline in application background?

Tags: react-native

**I need to check Internet Connection while Application Background**

Answer (score 10):

```
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';

NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
           if(isConnected)
           {
               console.log('Internet is connected');
           }
})
```

This above code is sufficient to check if there is active net connection or not

Comment: not working in iOS

Comment: this gives 'connected' response if my internet is down but connected to wifi. How can I detect that case ?

Comment: NetInfo is deprecated. This plugin needs to be used instead https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo

Answer (score 3):

**NetInfo** API is used for checking internet connection.

eg: `NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this._handleConnectionChange);`

refer https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html for more details.

Comment: Is it NetInfo can check internet connection in application background also ? @JainZz

Comment: I would check that code , but it can run only on application running time, that can't work in application background. @JainZz

Comment: If you want it to work in the background you'll have to implement your code in java/objective-c natively

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you're connected to internet but you're not online. and NetInfo cannot detect this situation and response of the below code is always true

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(res=>{
    if(res) {
      setIsConnected()
    }
  })
```

this made my application enter an infinite loop and request to server and get no response. so i fixed it by sending request to one of my apis (that doesn't need authorization) and if it had response, i set connectivity to true.

see below code:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(res=>{
    if(res) {
      this.checkConnectivity()
    }
  })
```

and then made the function checkConnectivity like below:

```
checkConnectivity(){
  return (
    Promise.resolve(
      getCategoriesApi().then(res=>{
        // console.log(res.data,"----------------is gettting info")
        setIsConnected()
      }).catch(err=>{
        // console.log(err.response,"-----------------not getting info")
      })
    )
   )
  }
```

where getCategoriesApi is:

```
Promise.resolve(Axios.get('my-url",mydata,myHeader()))
```

and it's working properly now.

hope it help someone in the similar situation.